# “A both ways word”

Tags: riddle, wordplay, language

```
This word spells the same backwards and forwards. What is it?
My letters are but three.
Reverse me I'm the same.
I'm black and blue, as you will see.
When once you've found my name.
```

---

*Source (this is not intended to be used to look up the answer, but is posted under [the policy on plagiarism of the Puzzle Stack Exchange website](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/a-policy-on-plagiarism)):*

> Source: The Queenslander (discontinued in 1939), without any specific author.

Comment: You need to post the source - otherwise, it's plagiarism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This word spells the same backwards and forwards. What is it?

> Eye

My letters are but three.

> Eye has three letters

Reverse me I'm the same.

> Eye is a palindrome - spelled the same forward and backwards, thus  reversed is the same.

I'm black and blue, as you will see.

> Eyes can be black (black eye - trauma) or blue (color of iris), or both...

When once you've found my name.

> *as you will see* -> eyes are used for seeing

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This is a good answer - for future reference, you can start every line with `>!` and end it with two spaces to make a multiline spoiler.

Comment: This answer does not use standard formatting. I will fix.

Comment: Also, "when you find the object" could be quite literal in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the formatting help. Coming from StackOverflow the spoiler format is new, as is the line-by-line response style. I will keep these styles in mind moving forward.